# Is there a way for typescript to infer that null values are no longer possible in an array?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array defined as follows:

```
const myArr: (MyType | null)[] = [];
```

And a function as follows:

```
const myFunc = (myObj: MyType) => /* do sth */;
```

If I filter myArr by not null, then try to map with myFunc, I get a compilation error because MyType | null is not assignable to to MyType. I understand why this is happening, but this is the filter and map code:

```js
class MyClass {

  private myArray: (string | null)[] = [];
  
  myFunc = (str: string) => str.toUpperCase();

  myOtherFunc = () => {
    this.myArray
      .filter(str => str !== null)
      .map(this.myFunc); // Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  }

}
```

If I cast the result of filter:

```
const notNullResults = this.myArray.filter(str => str !== null) as string[]
```

It compiles fine, but I don't like force casting like that. Is there a way for TypeScript to infer that the filtered array has a different type definition?

Comment: I don't think you will get around that.

Comment: [This open suggestion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16069) would have TypeScript automatically infer that `str => str !== null` is a type guard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need a type guard.

```
const notNullResults = this.myArray.filter((str): str is string => str !== null) // string[]
```

note that we're using the [`is`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) operator along with the built-in generic `string` type to indicate we're expecting only strings

Comment: `NonNullable` removes `null` from a type. Here `string` with `strictNullChecks` does not contain null anyway ....so `str is string` should work just as well

Comment: Or you can use a generic version, like `const isNotNull = <T>(value: T): value is NonNullable<T> => !!value;` then simply `myArray.filter(isNotNull)` results in `string[]`

Comment: Trying to use the NonNullable option.. am I missing something? Getting a "Cannot find name 'NonNullable'"

Comment: it was added in TS 2.8 i think, check your version.